# Having problem in automatically creating a customer field in database when some user signs up on website

Tags: python, django, postgresql

this is my **models.py**

```
class MyUser(AbstractBaseUser):
    email = models.EmailField(
        verbose_name='email address',
        max_length=255,
        unique=True,
    )
    mobile = models.CharField(max_length=12)
    first_name=models.CharField(max_length=20)
    last_name=models.CharField(max_length=20)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    is_admin = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    objects = MyUserManager()

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['mobile','first_name','last_name']


class Customer(models.Model):


    user=models.OneToOneField(MyUser,null=True,blank=True,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name=models.CharField(max_length=100,null=True)
    email=models.CharField(max_length=100)
    mobile=models.CharField(max_length=12)
    

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Order(models.Model):
    customer=models.ForeignKey(Customer,on_delete=models.SET_NULL,null=True,blank=True)
    date_ordered=models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    complete=models.BooleanField(default=False,null=True,blank=False)
    transaction_id=models.CharField(max_length=100,null=True)
```

and this is my **views.py**

```
def signup(request):

    if request.method == "POST":
        first_name=request.POST['first_name']
        last_name=request.POST['last_name']
        email=request.POST['email']
        mobile=request.POST['mobile']
        password=request.POST['password']
        cpassword=request.POST['cpassword']

        if password==cpassword:
            if User.objects.filter(email=email).exists():
                messages.info(request,'Email already in use')
                return redirect('signup')
            elif User.objects.filter(mobile=mobile).exists():
                messages.info(request,'Mobile Number already in use')
                return redirect('signup')
            else:
                user=User.objects.create_user(first_name=first_name,last_name=last_name,email=email,password=password,mobile=mobile)
                customer=Customer(user=user.email,mobile=mobile,name=first_name)
                customer.save();
                user.save();

                return redirect('/login/')
        else:
            messages.info(request,'Passwords not matching')
            return redirect('signup')
        
    else:
        return render(request,'signup.html')
```

I am working on a basic e-commerce website and to access the shopping cart the user must be registered.
The other model i am using is Order and which has a foreign key as customer.So basically to access the cart one has to be the customer.
The signup page that i have registers the users but also at the same time **I want to make him/her a customer as well** but i am not able to do it.
I tried using this

```
customer=Customer(user=user.email,mobile=mobile,name=first_name)
                    customer.save();
```

but i am getting error.
Please suggest some way so that whenever someone registers there is a customer object automatically created for him so that he can access the cart.
(i can manually set a customer in localhost/admin but thats extremely inefficient)

Comment: You can use signals to create customer. Learn more at https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2016/07/28/how-to-create-django-signals.html

Comment: I am a beginner to this.I couldnt understand that.It would be helpful if you tell me how to implement it

Answer (score 0):

Following is a basic example.
Create signals.py file inside your app where models.py is located.

```
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from django.dispatch import receiver
from django.conf import settings
# User = get_user_model()
User = settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL


@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def create_customer(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        Customer.objects.create(user=instance)

@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def save_customer(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    instance.customer.save()
```

Comment: Will this code work for me.Can you explain how this is working? Also do I have to remove that customer.save() from my views.py

Comment: The User model sends a signal on creation which is received by create_customer function ie. create_customer function runs when a new user is created.

Comment: SO will a customer be created (according to my models) when a user is created using your code. I tried it but i couldnt succeed.Also do we have to import something in modules.py for signals.py. Can you help me with the code

Comment: The above code should is a general example. It should work in your model what errors are you getting?

Comment: Customer has a foreign key as user. So this code is not able to save a customer with a user selected

Comment: That is why we are passing instance to user. Can you paste actual error that is shown in terminal or site?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/219025/discussion-between-itsmilann-and-vatsal-jain).

Comment: I am not getting any error.But still a customer isnt being saved when a user is created.Do i have to make any changes in models.py coz i havent made any